# Load .CSV File into a Tuple List and Combine Values VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

I'm using `VB.NET` and I'm trying to load a preexisting `CSV` file saved on the user's computer to a Tuple List of Strings that contains a point variable. I'm defining my list like this:

```
Dim loadedCsvList As List(Of Tuple(Of String, String, String, String, Point, String, String))
```

My `CSV` has ~800 rows and every single row has values that are formatted like this:

```
string1,string2,string3,string4,pointx,pointy,string5,string6
```

I'm trying to load the entire `CSV` into this type of list, but I want to combine the values in rows 5 (`pointx`) and 6 (`pointy`) of the `CSV` into a point inside the tuple list.

I know that if my list contained all strings and needed to be loaded into a list of tuples (that are also pure strings) then I could use a `for` loop to load each value in each column to a string. However, my CSV contained two separate values in two separate columns that needed to be combined into points and loaded into the CSV. I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

How can I load a CSV into a tuple list that contain points in seperate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, my csv looks like string, string, number, number, string.
[image]
The trick is to add `New Point(x, Y)` to the `Tuple.Create`.

I don't think I would use a Tuple. A class could have properties with meaningful names.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim loadedCsvList As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String, Point, String))
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Book1.csv")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim splits = line.Split(","c)
        loadedCsvList.Add(Tuple.Create(splits(0), splits(1), New Point(CInt(splits(2)), CInt(splits(3))), splits(4)))
    Next
    For Each item In loadedCsvList
        Debug.Print($"{item.Item1} {item.Item2} - {item.Item3.X}, {item.Item3.Y} {item.Item4}")
    Next
End Sub
```